# How to count the number of objects in a workspace?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to count the number of objects (Sheets, reports, sights, templates) in a workspace - I'm using:

```
workspaces = smart.Workspaces.get_workspace(
  workspace_id=XXXXXXXX,
  load_all=True)

x = len(workspaces.sights)

print (x)
```

Despite returning the list of all contents in workspaces, it's only retrieving the top level count on sights (as an example) - why is that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sights or Dashboards cannot contain anything inside them, like Sheets and Reports, so they won't have anything listed below them. If the Sight is found at the top level of the Workspace then there will be a `sights` attribute as a top level attribute on the Workspace object. That will be an array of every Sight at the top level of the Workspace. If there are Sights in folders below those you will see them listed as objects in the array for the specific folder. The top level Sights attribute will only account for Sights at the top level of the Workspace.
The object returned back when using `loadAll=true` will mimic the folder structure of the Workspace. To get a total count of every object type in the Workspace you will need to work through the object and count number of times the attribute appears to get a total count of each object type.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use the home request to get the home menu :

```
contents = smartsheet_client.Home.list_all_contents(include='source')
```

- Then find the correct workspace
- From there, count all items under that workspace.
- Then for every folder under the workspace count items (this step has to be recursive).